# Are cookies safe in a Heroku app on herokuapp.com?

Tags: cookies, heroku, cross-domain

I am developing an app, which I will deploy on Heroku. The app is only used within an `iframe` on another site, so I don't care about the domain name. I plan to deploy my app on `example.herokuapp.com` instead of using a custom domain on `example.com`.

My app uses cookies, and I want to be sure that others cannot manipulate my cookies to protect my app against [session fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation) and similar attacks. If `attacker.herokuapp.com` is able to set a cookie for `herokuapp.com`, browsers will not be able to protect me, since `herokuapp.com` is not a [public suffix](http://publicsuffix.org/). See http://w2spconf.com/2011/papers/session-integrity.pdf for a detailed description of the issue.

My question is: When browsers can't protect my users, will Heroku do it by blocking cookies for `herokuapp.com`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just wanted to post an update for anyone who ran across this question as I did. I was working on a similar problem, except that I wanted to purposefully allow access to the same cookie from two different heroku apps.

"herokuapp.com" and "herokussl.com" are now on the [Public Suffix List](http://publicsuffix.org/list/), so your cookies *should* be safe if they are set for one of those domains. I ended up having to use custom domains in order to share cookies across both apps.

Heroku also released an article on the topic: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to add a cookie from my Heroku app with the response header `Set-Cookie: name=value;Path=/;Domain=.herokuapp.com`, and to my disappointment, I could see the header intact in my browser. So the Heroku infrastructure does not detect and remove this cross-app supercookie.

I see three possible ways to protect a Heroku app against cross-app supercookies:

- Don't use cookies at all.
- Use a custom domain.
- Verify that each cookie was actually set by your app, and restrict it to the client's IP address by checking [the `X-Forwarded-For` header](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers).

My feature request to Heroku would be that they should filter HTTP responses that goes through their HTTP routing, such that applications hosted on their infrastructure cannot set cookies with `Domain=herokuapp.com`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that, as long as you set the cookie for `example.herokuapp.com`, then the cookie is safe from manipulation. The cookie will only be presented to the app running on `example.herokuapp.com` and to `herokuapp.com` (where no app runs).

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to say. Yes, if I have already set the cookie myself for example.herokuapp.com, I am safe, but when I receive a request that contains a cookie, I have no way of knowing if I have set it myself on example.herokuapp.com, or if it was set by someone else on herokuapp.com. If in your last sentence mean "and" instead of "on", then the cookie set by my app will not be presented to the bare herokuapp.com domain, but it is not the cookies set by my app that I am worried about.

Comment: Why are you worried by cookies set by other sites though? If you store sensitive information in the cookie or if the cookies are used to store session info, you should encrypt and then sign the cookie. You can read details here: https://github.com/appharbor/AppHarbor.Web.Security

Comment: Signing and encrypting the cookies does not prevent replay attacks. Carol visits my site and gets a session cookie. Alice visits Carol's site and the site sets the session cookie that I gave to Carol for the herokuapp.com domain. Then Alice visits my site, and my site will receive Carol's session cookie, and will think she is Carol. On my site it will mean that Alice may be automatically logged in using Carol's user account, and she might enter some private data without noticing that she is logged in to Carol's account.

Comment: Hm, I don't follow. If you set your cookie using at the myapp.herokuapp.com domain, then it's not going to be presented anywhere else and no one will be able to replay it.

Comment: You are correct that my cookies will not be presented anywhere else, but what I am worried about is that somebody else's cookies can be presented to me. Do you know why browsers use public suffixes (see RFC 6265 http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265 ) in their cookie handling?

Comment: Here is an example of a vulnerable application: http://cookie-user.herokuapp.com/source and here is an attack on it: http://cookie-attacker.herokuapp.com/source . (1) Play around with http://cookie-user.herokuapp.com/ and see that the genuine cookie works. (2) Remove the genuine cookie. (3) Set the fake cookie using http://cookie-attacker.herokuapp.com/ (4) Observe that http://cookie-user.herokuapp.com/ sees the fake cookie. (The example does not sign or encrypt the cookie or track it on the server side, but the attack would work even if it did)