# unable to send cookie to backend with heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I'm doing an axios request to my backend, and set a cookie :

```
axios.get(`http://mybackend/somepage`)
     .then((response) => {
        res.cookie('token', response.data.token)
        res.send(`click here <a href="http://mybackend/profile">profile</a>`)
})
```

On my backend, I use express with "cookie-parser".

Clicking the link to the backend, I get this with `console.log(req.cookies)` : "[Object: null prototype] {}".

Looking at the request headers, the cookie is not even sent.

I don't have this problem when I test on localhost.

Is it because it's not possible to exchange cookies between two domains (in this case 2 heroku apps) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can not send cookies between two Heroku apps... 
`*.herokuapp.com` has been added to the Public Suffix List which means you can not exchange cookies between those sites.

> herokuapp.com is included in the Mozilla Foundation’s Public Suffix List. This list is used in recent versions of several browsers, such as Firefox, Chrome and Opera, to limit how broadly a cookie may be scoped. In other words, in browsers that support the functionality, applications in the herokuapp.com domain are prevented from setting cookies for *.herokuapp.com. Note that *.herokuapp.com cookies can currently be set in Internet Explorer, but this behavior should not be relied upon and may change in the future. 
> [Article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com)

[Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519671/are-cookies-safe-in-a-heroku-app-on-herokuapp-com) StackOverflow question

**FIXES**:

- You can use a custom domain name
- Have your second site available at `firstSite.herokuapp.com/secondSite`

Comment: Is it the same with sessions ?